# Updating cassandra list collection is creating tombstones

Tags: cassandra, cql, tombstone

Cassandra version 3.11.3

I have a record with some set and list collections.
Using the sets with adding/removing data seems to have no or very limited tombstone creation.
Using a list column however seems to be creating a tombstone per query.

I was under the impression this was fixed in this [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10547,).

Am I doing something wrong?

Doing this 10k times generates no tombstones: (assume partition doesn't exist prior)

```
update "Record" Set "AllSetItems" = "AllSetItems" + {'abc'} where "RecordId" = 5 and "Field" = 'xyz';
update "Record" Set "AllSetItems" = "AllSetItems" - {'abc'} where "RecordId" = 5 and "Field" = 'xyz';
```

Thus this query works fine:

```
Select * from "Record" where "RecordId" = 5 and "Field" = 'xyz';
```

Doing this 10k times generates a lot of tombstones: (assume partition doesn't exist prior)

```
update "Record" Set "AllListItems" = "AllListItems" + ['abc'] where "RecordId" = 5 and "Field" = 'xyz';
update "Record" Set "AllListItems" = "AllListItems" - ['abc'] where "RecordId" = 5 and "Field" = 'xyz';
```

After the updates this query fails due to too many tombstones:

```
Select * from "Record" where "RecordId" = 5 and "Field" = 'xyz';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is working as expected. Read this article (although it's a bit dated) and see if it explains your situation.

https://jsravn.com/2015/05/13/cassandra-tombstones-collections/#lists